# p-accordionTab opens with distorted UI on click of different anchor tag

Tags: angular, primeng

Use Case:- I am using primeng 5.2.0, p-accordionTab is already close, I am trying to open tab by clicking on some other anchor tag on the same page by setting selected input property true.

Result:- For some time accordion tab gets overlapped with another below tab.

Is there any workaround to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying selected property in this form?:

```
[selected]="true"
```